# Populate list box with a named range

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, named-ranges

I'm working on my first ever VBA project, and need a bit of absolute newbie guidance.

1. I have a submission form that staff will be using to submit their daily KPIs.
2. I have a list box control in a user form called "lstName" that employees will use to select their name before submitting the form
3. Employee names are stored in a named range on "Sheet11" called "EmpName".

I want to direct the list box to draw the list of names from the "EmpName" range on Sheet11; but don't know how I would do this in VBA. I was going to use RowSource to point the list box to the data, but I am lost as to how to do this.

Really simple question I know, and it has probably been answered in some way on the site, but since I'm completely new to VBA, the answers were beyond me. If someone could provide a stepped out answer that explains what the code is doing that would be amazing!

Comment: What `ListBox` are we talking about? UserForm/ActiveX/FormControl? Approach differs for each.

Comment: It's a Form Control :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your Userform and your ListBox, turn on Properties Window (View -> Properties or F4)

In the Properties Window navigate to the `RowSource` property and type `Sheet11!EmpName`

A simple `boo` example

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was sure it was that simple!
No doubt I will blunder through the rest of this form for a while yet :)

Comment: @cazzac It's not a `Form Control`. It is a `ListBox Control` in a user form :)

Comment: @L42 well it's actually an ActiveX type of Control. by "Form" I think the OP actually meant the Listbox control on a UserForm.