# Auto populate Combobox from range

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013, vba

I am using Excel 2013 and I have written the below code to auto populate a combobox from a range for one of my userforms. I have the combobox named "Times"

Sometimes this populates the list and other times it gives a blank list even though the range did not change.

Any idea how to stop this and just have it work everytime?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Sheets("Backend").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Times.RowSource = Sheets("Backend").Range("E1:E96").Address
    Sheets("Backend").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a different way to do this now that works. Thanks to this post.

[Populate list box with a named range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534710/populate-list-box-with-a-named-range)