# How to populate a listbox based on a conditional statement

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, conditional-statements

I'm trying to populate a listbox in a userform based on what is in a cell on the active sheet.
I am trying to refer to a named range, which is on another sheet.

For example, I want to check that the cell says "hi" then go to the named range on another sheet called "hi" and bring the values in that range into the listbox.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Populate Combobox Based on Cell Value
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("cellTest").Text
    
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "hi") Then
        'Code to bring in routes from named range called "hi"
        ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("hi").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

I would repeat the "if-end if" segment of code multiple times based on other cell values, such as "hey" or "what's up."

I get

> run-time 1004 error

Comment: A look at help will tell you that `RowSource` requires an address, i.e. a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534710/populate-list-box-with-a-named-range

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had renamed "Sheet 4" as "DropDown" because it was where I was storing all of my dropdown menus. The code should read:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Populate Combobox Based on Cell Value
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("cellTest").Text

    If InStr(1, celltxt, "hi") Then
        'Code to bring in routes from named range called "hi"
        ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("DropDown").Range("hi").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

And that works great!